# How to take command line input to a fabfile?

Tags: python, fabric

I want to give some input (initial configuration to a fabric file)
Something like:

```
fab deploy MyProject
```

where MyProject is the string I want to input. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to specify `"MyProject"` thus:

```
fab deploy:MyProject
```

And your function (in your `fabfile.py`) will look thus:

```
def deploy(project):
    ...
```

where `project` equals `"MyProject"`.

([more info](http://fabric.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/fab.html#per-task-arguments))

Answer (score 0):

In your fabfile:

```
# fabfile.py
# ...
if not hasattr(env, 'my_setting'):
    env.my_setting = 'default'
# ...
```

Run fab script:

```
fab --set=my_setting=my_value task
```

More info:

```
fab --help
```